# Fetching Data From MySQL Server in Android

Tags: php, android, json

I would like to ask if any of you have experienced this scenario wherein the server returns a response of an html page.

```
02-06 20:41:45.835  31281-31281/com.pupt.rois E/Internet Status:﹕ Has Internet
02-06 20:41:46.135  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ propertyValue:true
02-06 20:41:46.136  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ [socket][20] connection /199.83.132.226:80;LocalPort=36360(0)
02-06 20:41:46.137  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ [CDS]connect[/199.83.132.226:80] tm:90
02-06 20:41:46.385  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ [socket][/192.168.1.10:36360] connected
02-06 20:41:46.385  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ [CDS]rx timeout:0
02-06 20:41:46.387  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ [CDS]SO_SND_TIMEOUT:0
02-06 20:41:46.391  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ >doSendRequest
02-06 20:41:46.393  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ <doSendRequest
02-06 20:41:46.441  31281-31281/com.pupt.rois I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5cc75fb8) fps:22.65, dur:1015.51, max:106.31, min:13.32
02-06 20:41:46.718  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ [CDS]close[36360]
02-06 20:41:46.718  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:36360]
02-06 20:41:46.719  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:36360]
02-06 20:41:46.720  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois E/response﹕ <html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script>
(function(){function getSessionCookies(){cookieArray=new Array();var cName=/^\s?incap_ses_/;var c=document.cookie.split(";");for(var i=0;i<c.length;i++){key=c[i].substr(0,c[i].indexOf("="));value=c[i].substr(c[i].indexOf("=")+1,c[i].length);if(cName.test(key)){cookieArray[cookieArray.length]=value}}return cookieArray}function setIncapCookie(vArray){try{cookies=getSessionCookies();digests=new Array(cookies.length);for(var i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){digests[i]=simpleDigest((vArray)+cookies[i])}res=vArray+",digest="+(digests.join())}catch(e){res=vArray+",digest="+(encodeURIComponent(e.toString()))}createCookie("___utmvc",res,20)}function simpleDigest(mystr){var res=0;for(var i=0;i<mystr.length;i++){res+=mystr.charCodeAt(i)}return res}function createCookie(name,value,seconds){if(seconds){var date=new Date();date.setTime(date.getTime()+(seconds*1000));var expires="; expires="+date.toGMTString()}else{var expires=""}document.cookie=name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/"}function test(o){var res="";var vArray=new Array();for(test in o){switch(o[test]){case"exists":try{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+typeof(eval(test)))}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+e)}break;case"value":try{vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+eval(test).toString())}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent(test+"="+e)}break;case"plugins":try{p=navigator.plugins;pres="";for(a in p){pres+=(p[a]["description"]+" ").substring(0,20)}vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugins="+pres)}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugins="+e)}break;case"plugin":try{a=navigator.plugins;for(i in a){f=a[i]["filename"].split(".");if(f.length==2){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin="+f[1]);break}}}catch(e){vArray[vArray.length]=encodeURIComponent("plugin="+e)}break}}vArray=vArray.join();return vArray}var o={navigator:"exists","navigator.vendor":"value",opera:"exists",ActiveXObject:"exists","navigator.appName":"value",platform:"plugin",webkitURL:"exists","navigator.plugins.length==0":"value",_phantom: "exists"};try{setIncapCookie(test(o));document.createElement("img").src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e="+Math.random()}catch(e){img=document.createElement("img");img.src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWKMTFSR=1&e="+e}})();
</script>
<script>
(function() {
var z="";var b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

02-06 20:41:46.721  31281-31323/com.pupt.rois E/TAAAAG﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

This is my code to fetch the value

```
public class validate extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

            JSONArray jArray;
            String result, phpResponse;
            boolean error;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                    try{
                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.url)+"/PUP_ROIS/mobile/loginlogout.php");
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "true"));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", dbObj.getRegistrationID()));
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line;
                            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
                                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                            result=sb.toString();
                            Log.e("response", result);
                            error=true;
                            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                            error=false;   
                            return null;
                    }catch(Exception e){
                            error=true;
                            Log.e("TAAAAG", e.toString());
                    }
                    return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                    try{
                            if(!error){
                                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                    //STUDENT
                                    if(type.equals("1")){
                                            String type = json_data.getString("type");
                                            String username = json_data.getString("id");
                                            String name = json_data.getString("name");
                                            String birthday = json_data.getString("birthday");
                                            String gender = json_data.getString("gender");
                                            String email = json_data.getString("email");
                                            String yrbatch = json_data.getString("yrbatch");
                                            String course = json_data.getString("course");
                                            dbObj.insertToUserTable("1", type, username, name, birthday, gender, email, yrbatch, course);  
                                    }
                                    //ALUMNI
                                    else if (type.equals("2"))
                                    {
                                            String type = json_data.getString("type");
                                            String username = json_data.getString("id");
                                            String name = json_data.getString("name");
                                            String birthday = json_data.getString("birthday");
                                            String gender = json_data.getString("gender");
                                            String email = json_data.getString("Email");
                                            String yrbatch = json_data.getString("yrbatch");
                                            String course = json_data.getString("course");
                                            dbObj.insertToUserTable("2", type, username, name, birthday, gender, email, yrbatch, course);
                                    }
                                    //ADMIN
                                    else{
                                            String id = json_data.getString("id");
                                            String type = json_data.getString("type");
                                            String name = json_data.getString("name");
                                            String username = json_data.getString("username");
                                            dbObj.insertToUserTable(id, type, username, name, "", "", "", "", "");
                                    }
                                    checkIfLoggedin();
                            }
                            else{
                                    showMessage("Invalid Username or Password");
                                    enable(true);
                            }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    }      
            }
    }
```

this is the code from my server, Im using PHP

```
<?php
// ---------------------------[DEFAULTS]-------------------------------
include 'connections/config.php';  
include 'send_message.php';                              
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');    
mysqli_query(connect(), 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');  
// ---------------------------[/DEFAULTS]-------------------------------

$type=$_POST['type'];
$login=$_POST['login'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=sha1($_POST['password']);
$regid=$_POST['regid'];
// TYPE 1: STUDENT
// TYPE 2: ALIMNI
// TYPE 3: OFFICE
if($login=="true"){
    if($type==1){
        $sql = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT '".$type."' as type, stud_id as id,
        CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name, ' ', middle_name) as name,
        birthdate as birthday, gender, email, year as yrbatch, course
        FROM tbl_students
        WHERE stud_id='".$username."'
        AND password='".$password."'");




    }
    else if($type==2){
        $sql = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT '".$type."' as type, alumniID as id,
        CONCAT(lastName, ', ', firstName, ' ', middleName) as name,
        CONCAT(birthYear, '-', birthMonth, '-', birthDay) as birthday,
        gender, Email, batch as yrbatch, course
        FROM alumni_tblalumni
        WHERE alumniID='".$username."'
        AND `Password`='".$password."'
        ");
    }
    else if($type==3){
        $sql = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT '".$type."' as type, office_id as id,
        faculty_incharge as name,
        faculty_username as username
        FROM tbl_office
        WHERE faculty_username='".$username."'
        AND faculty_password='".$password."'");
    }  
    $output=null;
    //if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){      

        $sql1 = "UPDATE tbl_android SET user='".$username."', type='".$type."', lastlog=NOW() WHERE regid='".$regid."'";
        $result1 = mysqli_query(connect(), $sql1);

        if($type==1){
        $sql2 = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT CONCAT(last_name, ', ', first_name, ' ', middle_name) as name
        FROM tbl_students
        WHERE stud_id='".$username."'
        AND password='".$password."'");

        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
             $names = $row["name"];
         }

        else if($type==2){
        $sql2 = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT CONCAT(lastName, ', ', firstName, ' ', middleName) as name

        FROM alumni_tblalumni
        WHERE studNum='".$username."'
        AND Password='".$password."'");
             $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                 $names = $row["name"];
             }

        else if($type==3){
        $sql2 = mysqli_query(connect(), "SELECT
        faculty_incharge as name

        FROM tbl_office
        WHERE faculty_username='".$username."'
        AND faculty_password='".$password."'");

         $row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                 $names = $row["name"];
    }  



        $sendObj = new send_message();
        if($result1==1)
            $sendObj -> send($regid, $names." has Successfully Log In");
        else
            $sendObj -> send($regid, "Cannot Update");
        while($result=$sql->fetch_assoc())
            $output[]=$result;    
        print(json_encode($output));
    }// login = true
    else
        echo "Invalid Username or Password";    
}
else{
    $sql = "UPDATE tbl_android SET user='-', type='-', lastlog=NOW() WHERE regid='".$regid."'";
    $result = mysqli_query(connect(), $sql);
    echo "Logged out";
}
?>
```

Please point out what I did wrong and why is that the response of my page is an html ROBOT, Thanks everyone btw I'm using ipage as the server

Comment: Sorry for the link just replace the dot with (.) cant post due to lack of my reputation and this is my first post in stackoverflow cheers to everyone!

Comment: Please put your code into the question. If it's too long then post just the relevant sections.

Comment: please see the description of the question hehe I've included several pastebin

Comment: It's recommended to paste at least the relevant code in your question to help prevent link-rot. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156631/while-reviewing-what-should-be-done-if-code-or-an-image-from-another-source-is and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202815/how-should-i-show-lengthy-code-on-stack-overflow

Comment: oh sorry my bad, thanks Tom

Comment: What does the PHP code look like?

Comment: @SogeKing clearly you are not hitting the right page, you are the server admin, only you can debug it

Comment: hmmmm it just happens to return an html page as a JSON response with META NAME="robots" and I really dont know what to do because this is working before